# From checkboxes are not unchecked when form submitted

Tags: jquery, reactjs, forms, checkbox

I am currently working on a ReactJS project.
I have a form that should console.log the form fields onSubmit as object.
In that form, I have few checkboxes (pulled from the DB by RestAPI and rendered by other react component).

After submit, the checkboxes are not being UNCHECKED.
My problem is that when I am unchecking them manually, it adds the unchecked data to the data object.

How can I uncheck the checkboxes onSubmit without doing it manually?

Here is the page code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import FCIngredient from '../FunctionalComps/FCIngredient';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

const apiUrl = 'https://somelocalhost/'

export default function NewRecipePage() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])
    const [recipeIngredients, setRecipeIngredients] = useState([])

    const addIngredientToRecipe = (ingredientObject) => {
        let tmpIngArr =[...recipeIngredients,ingredientObject];
        setRecipeIngredients([...tmpIngArr])
        tmpIngArr = [];
    }
    const Go2Home = () => {
        navigate('/');
    }
    const NewRecipeSubmited = (event) => {
        //$(".checkClass").attr("checked", false);//didn't work

        const recipeObject = {
            Name: event.target.recName.value,
            ImageUrl: event.target.recUrl.value,
            CoockingMethod: event.target.recMethod.value,
            CoockingTime:event.target.recTime.value
        }
        console.log('recipeObject: ',recipeObject);
        console.log('recipeIngredients: ',recipeIngredients);
        let cleaningArr = [];
        setRecipeIngredients(cleaningArr);
        event.preventDefault();

    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            })
        })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIngredients(result)
                    console.log(ingredients);
                },
                (error) => {
                });
    },[])


    return (
        <div style={{ color: 'white', width: '100%' }}>
            <h1>New Recipe</h1>
            <button onClick={Go2Home} >Back Home</button> <br />

            <form onSubmit={NewRecipeSubmited}>
                <input name="recName" type="text" placeholder='Recipe Name' /><br />
                <input name="recMethod" type="text" placeholder='Cooking Method' /><br />
                <input name="recTime" type="text" placeholder='Cooking Time' /><br />
                <input name="recUrl" type="url" placeholder='Recipe imageURL' /><br />
                <p>Please choose the ingredients for your recipe!</p>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {ingredients.map((ing) =>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" className='checkClass' onChange={() => {addIngredientToRecipe(ing)}} id={ing.IngredientId}/>
                            <FCIngredient ingredient={ing} key={ing.IngredientId} /></div>)}
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Add your new recipe!</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why you didn't use the checked property in your input? if you click twice the same checkbox  you see the check/uncheck or not ? these questions helps me to understand the problem thanks

Comment: @BruNo
checked property -  I don't usually use this checkbox property, I thought that this was default unchecked.
If I click the same checkbox twice I do see the V sign shown and hidden.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" className='checkClass' checked={recipeIngredients.some((el) => el === ing)} onChange={() => {addIngredientToRecipe(ing)}} id={ing.IngredientId}/>

try to add the checked property like that i think it should fix your issue

Comment: This worked, THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to add a + on the comment , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the code is almost right. Here are the required changes:

1. You just have to add a boolean field `isChecked` in each ingredient object.
2. In the `addIngredientToReceipe()` method toggle the isChecked field of the selected ingredient object
3. In the `NewRecipeSubmitted` function, set `isChecked` to `false` for each ingredient object and then call `setIngredients()` with the modified array

Check the in-line comments to follow the approach:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import FCIngredient from '../FunctionalComps/FCIngredient';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const apiUrl = 'https://somelocalhost/'

export default function NewRecipePage() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])
    const [recipeIngredients, setRecipeIngredients] = useState([])

    const addIngredientToRecipe = (ingredientObject) => {
        let tmpIngArr =[...recipeIngredients,ingredientObject];
        setRecipeIngredients([...tmpIngArr])
        // 3. Find the ingredient in the array and toggle the checked status
        let newIngredients = [...ingredients];
        for (let i = 0; i < newIngredients.length; i++) {
            if (newIngredients[i].IngredientId === ingredientObject.IngredientId) {
                newIngredients[i].isChecked = !newIngredients[i].isChecked;
                break;
            }
        }
        // 4. Update ingredients' state
        setIngredients(newIngredients);
        tmpIngArr = [];
    }
    const Go2Home = () => {
        navigate('/');
    }
    const NewRecipeSubmited = (event) => {
        const recipeObject = {
            Name: event.target.recName.value,
            ImageUrl: event.target.recUrl.value,
            CoockingMethod: event.target.recMethod.value,
            CoockingTime:event.target.recTime.value
        }
        console.log('recipeObject: ',recipeObject);
        console.log('recipeIngredients: ',recipeIngredients);
        let cleaningArr = [];
        setRecipeIngredients(cleaningArr);
        // 5. Loop through each ingredients and set the isChecked to false
        let newIngredients = [...ingredients];
        for (let i = 0; i < newIngredients.length; i++) {
            newIngredients[i].isChecked = false;
        }
        // 6. Update ingredients' state
        setIngredients(newIngredients);
        event.preventDefault();

    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            })
        })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    // 1. Note the new field `isChecked` here
                    setIngredients(result.map(i => ({...i, isChecked: false})))
                    console.log(ingredients);
                },
                (error) => {
                });
    },[])


    return (
        <div style={{ color: 'white', width: '100%' }}>
            <h1>New Recipe</h1>
            <button onClick={Go2Home} >Back Home</button> <br />

            <form onSubmit={NewRecipeSubmited}>
                <input name="recName" type="text" placeholder='Recipe Name' /><br />
                <input name="recMethod" type="text" placeholder='Cooking Method' /><br />
                <input name="recTime" type="text" placeholder='Cooking Time' /><br />
                <input name="recUrl" type="url" placeholder='Recipe imageURL' /><br />
                <p>Please choose the ingredients for your recipe!</p>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {ingredients.map((ing) =>
                        <div>
                            {/* 2. Note the controlled checkbox here */}
                            <input type="checkbox" className='checkClass' checked={ing.isChecked} onChange={() => {addIngredientToRecipe(ing)}} id={ing.IngredientId}/>
                            <FCIngredient ingredient={ing} key={ing.IngredientId} /></div>)}
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Add your new recipe!</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thing is that the ingredientsArr is retrieved from the DB with fixed fields (and is used for other components in the project). Do you know of a way to add a field to the ingredientObject in the page itself and that will not affect the data moving to other components?

Comment: Yup, create another hook, which is an object that maps ingredientId to isChecked status. Say you call it `ingredientIdChecked`. So then, instead of modifying the original `ingredients` array, each time some event is triggered, you will be modifying that separate object. And this object will be confined only to this component.

Answer (score 0):

@Borni.Mr
helped me figuring this out:
By giving a 'checked' property to each checkbox, the jQuery.att.checked is now working:

Original Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" className='checkClass' onChange={() => {addIngredientToRecipe(ing)}} id={ing.IngredientId}/>
```

Fixed Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" className='checkClass' checked={recipeIngredients.some((el) => el === ing)} onChange={() => {addIngredientToRecipe(ing)}} id={ing.IngredientId}/>
```